# commons.net FTPSClient.storeFile doesn't throw IOException if connection with server is lost

Tags: timeout

Background:

I'm attempting to add some level fault tolerance to an application that uses Apache Commons.net FTPSClient to transfer files. If the connection between the client and server fails, I'd like to capture the produced exception/return code, log the details, and attempt to reconnect/retry the transfer.

What works:

The retrieveFile() method. If the connection fails, (i.e. I disable the server's public interface), I receive a CopyStreamException caused by a SocketTimeoutException after the amount of time I specified as the timeout.

What doesn't work:

The storeFile() method. If I initiate a transfer via storeFile() and disable the server's public interface, the storeFile() method blocks/hangs indefinitely with out throwing any exceptions.

Here is a simple app that hangs if the connection is terminated:

```
public class SmallTest {

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SmallTest.class);

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(true);
    FTPSCredentials creds = new FTPSCredentials("host", "usr", "pass", 
            "/keystore/ftpclient.jks", "pass", 
            "/keystore/rootca.jks");

    String file = "/file/jdk-7u21-linux-x64.rpm";
    String destinationFile = "/jdk-7u21-linux-x64.rpm";

    client.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getValidateServerCertificateTrustManager());
    client.setKeyManager(creds.getKeystoreManager());

    client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));
    client.setCopyStreamListener(createListener());

    client.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    client.setDefaultTimeout(5000);

    client.connect(creds.getHost(), 990);   

    client.setSoTimeout(5000);
    client.setDataTimeout(5000);

    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(client.getReplyCode())) {
        client.disconnect();
        log.error("ERROR: " + creds.getHost() + " refused the connection");
    } else {
        if (client.login(creds.getUser(), creds.getPass())) {
            log.debug("Logged in as " + creds.getUser());

            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();     
            client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE);
            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            log.debug("Invoking storeFile()");

            if (!client.storeFile(destinationFile, inputStream)) {
                log.error("ERROR: Failed to store " + file
                        + " on remote host. Last reply code: "
                        + client.getReplyCode());
            } else {
                log.debug("Stored the file...");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            client.logout();
            client.disconnect();
        } else {
            log.error("Could not log into " + creds.getHost());
        }
    }
}

private static CopyStreamListener createListener(){
    return new CopyStreamListener(){
        private long megsTotal = 0;
        @Override
        public void bytesTransferred(CopyStreamEvent event) {
            bytesTransferred(event.getTotalBytesTransferred(), event.getBytesTransferred(), event.getStreamSize());
        }
        @Override
        public void bytesTransferred(long totalBytesTransferred,
                int bytesTransferred, long streamSize) {
            long megs = totalBytesTransferred / 1000000;
            for (long l = megsTotal; l < megs; l++) {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
            megsTotal = megs;
        }
    };
}
```

Is there any way to make the connection ACTUALLY timeout?

SW Versions:

Commons.net v3.3
Java 7
CentOS 6.3

Thanks in advance,

- Joe

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem, and I think that I was able to get something that seems to work with the desired timeout behavior when I unplug the ethernet cable on my laptop.

I use 'storeFileStream' instead of 'storeFile', and then use 'completePendingCommand' to finish the transfer. You can check the Apache commons docs for 'completePendingCommand' to see an example of this kind of transfer. It took about 15 mins for it to timeout for me. One other thing: the aforementioned docs include calling 'isPositiveIntermediate' to check for an error, but this wasn't working. I replaced it with 'isPositivePreliminary' and now it seems to work. I'm not sure if that's actually correct, but it's the best I've found so far.